# One yasnippet snippet for multiple modes

Tags: yasnippet

I have the following snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# contributor: Song Qiang <tsiangsung@gmail.com>
# key: m
# group: Math
# name: Inline math \( ... \)
# --
\\($1\\)$0
```

and I want it to be available for both `latex-mode` and `org-mode`. How can this be achieved? I could symlink, but I'm trying to find a smarter way.

Comment: c-mode and c++-mode both share snippets from cc-mode, you can check how they do it. There should a ".yas-parents" file.

Comment: You can try yankpad, it worth a try ! https://github.com/Kungsgeten/yankpad https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkkyE7d0Bpc&feature=youtu.be

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [Yasnippet documentation](http://joaotavora.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-organization.html#org7468fa9) explains that you will need to include a `.yas-parents` file with the parent modes:

> It's very useful to have certain modes share snippets between themselves. To do this, choose a mode subdirectory and place a `.yas-parents` containing a whitespace-separated list of other mode names. When you reload those modes become parents of the original mode.

```
.
|-- c-mode
|   |-- .yas-parents    # contains "cc-mode text-mode"
|   `-- printf
|-- cc-mode
|   |-- for
|   `-- while
|-- java-mode
|   |-- .yas-parents    # contains "cc-mode text-mode"
|   `-- println
`-- text-mode
    |-- email
    `-- time
```

Hence, you could, for example, put your snippet in a `text-mode` directory, and then, in the `latex-mode` and `org-mode` directories, include a `.yas-parents` file that include the text `text-mode`.

Comment: However, if I have well understood, you can only share **entire** modes, but not **individual** snippets across several modes?

Answer (score 2):

A few more approaches for sharing snippets between modes:

1. Let's say you want certain snippets to be shared in *both* modes: `html-mode` & `css-mode`:

   You need to create a separate folder and give it a unique name like `html-css-mode` where you put the snippets you want to reuse.

   Once that's done you need to require this virtual mode in `html-mode` & `css-mode` folders by creating a `.yas-parents` file with `html-css-mode` content matching your virtual mode name.
2. If your snippet belongs to more that one mode or you're want to take a lazy approach - you can put your snippets into `fundamental-mode` folder which is available in all modes.