# How to get a global available yasnippet snippet?

Tags: yasnippet

How to create a yasnippet snippet which is available in all modes?
Lets say I have a function which evaluates the sexpr before the cursor and replaces is with its value, [Link to code](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/43b42y/i_just_realized_emacs_has_a_fast_infix_calculator/czhc45r/).
Also I caught me to regular use following sexpr `(format "0x%x" ${1:number})` which prints a number in hex. Converting this into a snippet is easy, but:

**Question:** How can I tell yasnippet, to make it available in every major-mode?

*Note:* I read the [question about multiple modes](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10960/one-yasnippet-snippet-for-multiple-modes), but this seems to be much work and fiddling and I would have to create a directory in snippets-dir for every possible mode.

Comment: I don't have a solution with yasnippet.  [yankpad](https://github.com/Kungsgeten/yankpad) might come in handy here. Besides you can switch category (mode) very easily with it.

Comment: @DJJ thanks. I don't think this will work for me, because I'm using company in conjunction with `:with yasnippet` to auto complete these snippets. :)