# How to use yasnippets from js- and css- modes in html-mode?

Tags: yasnippet, html, web-mode

I have latest YASnippet package installed on GNU Emacs 27.2 via MELPA. Snippets work, for example in `*.js` files, `let` expands to snippet after hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd>. However, when I edit HTML file (in html-mode), the JS inside `<script>` tag does not use YAS. Also, CSS snippets don't work in `<style>`.

I tried web-mode, but it fixes only JS.

Are there other solutions?

Comment: I did not further look into it, but [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10960/one-yasnippet-snippet-for-multiple-modes) general answer might help you on your way.

Comment: @dalanicolai Thank you, it seems to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10960/one-yasnippet-snippet-for-multiple-modes) mentioned by @dalanicolai helped a lot: I just had to edit `~/.emacs.d/snippets/html-mode/.yas-parents` to contain `css-mode js-mode`.